# Possibility of finding two max values(with difference of more than one) from an array while filling it simultaneously

Tags: c, max

[image: Hough_transform for two lines]

I am trying to find maximum value and maximum + 3 value from an array while filling it simultaneously. I tried the following code, but it is not proper algorithm.

```
for(x = image_height; x--; ){
    for(y = image_width; y--; ){
        if(*((in_image + x * image_width )+ y)){
            for(theta = -90; theta <= 180; theta++){
                rho = x * mycos(theta) + y * mysin(theta);
                if(rho > 0 && rho < MAX_POSSIBLE_RHO){
                    g_hough_array[(int)rho][(int)theta + 90]++;
                    if(rho == 0) continue;
                    if(max_intensity < g_hough_array[(int)rho][(int)theta + 90]){
                        max_intensity = g_hough_array[(int)rho][(int)theta + 90];
                        *max_theta = theta;
                        *max_rho = rho;
                    }else{
                        if(theta < (*max_theta) + 3 && theta > (*max_theta) - 3) continue;
                        if(max_intensity2 < g_hough_array[(int)rho][(int)theta + 90]){
                            max_intensity2 = g_hough_array[(int)rho][(int)theta + 90];
                            *max_theta2 = theta;
                            *max_rho2 = rho;
                            if(max_intensity2 == max_intensity){
                                float temp = (*max_theta);
                                (*max_theta) = (*max_theta2);
                                (*max_theta2) = temp;
                                temp = (*max_rho);
                                (*max_rho) = (*max_rho2);
                                (*max_rho2) = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking is it even possible to find this kind of two values at the same time of filling an array?
I want to avoid extra loop to find second maximum value.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum + 3 value"? Just the maximum, incremented by 3?

Comment: yes, i.e if max val is 15 max2 needs to be less than 12 (i.e. 15-3).

Comment: I think that can work. But you probably need to remove the if-else, and always test & search for both maxima. Then, for your second `maximum2`, use a `temp` variable first, check that that is smaller than your `maximum1 - 3`, and if so, assign temp properly to `maximum2`.

Comment: Posting the types of the variables (their declarations) would   add clarity.

Comment: @AshokSharma842 - Just because inquiring minds want to know... What is that image? It looks like some type of flowfield, whether fluid or electromagnetic I can't tell, It's not a mach-diamond given the profile of the leading boundary (unless it is a reflected shockwave within a propulsion exhaust)-- so what gives?

Comment: You should split this code up by using functions. It is quite unreadable.

Comment: Your loop bounds are suspicious.  Within the loop body, `x` takes values from `image_height` down to 1, and `y` takes values from `image_width` down to 1.  Supposing that `in_image` points to a block of `image_height * image_width` pixels, all of which you want to examine, your indexing is off by one throughout.

Comment: @Evert Hmmm... let me try that too... Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is a simple hough transform of two lines intersecting. Photo is captured and this function finds those lines through this plot.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think its simple "value to zero" loop. the test condition, says "Is i non-zero? If so, decrement it and continue".
for(int i = 10; i--; )printf("%d",i);
prints: 9876543210

Comment: What if brightness of "wing" of point a , greater that point b itself??Compiler doesn't know what those two objects are (or maybe doesn't care).Compiler (best-case scenario) can only "anticipate" pixels , if you make clear to it that this is an image file. –

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Thats the issue. I want to eliminate the vicinity pixels and count the other peak value, while I the peaks are still accumulating. 
I am trying to achieve this though simple algorithm and single loop.

Comment: What this photo is showing to us?Comets?

Comment: @AshokSharma842 - thank you. With wikipedia consulted, curiosity satisfied. It strangely looked somewhat like mach-diamonds in rocket exhaust with a side component of flow imparted by -- something very very bad happening after launch...

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis It is Hough Transform of two lines, the brightest points show the line with (theta,rho). Two such points in theta, rho plane shows there are two lines in the x,y plane.

Comment: I see , so what are the distinct characterists??Maybe the haze around the point?

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

capture the first two values as the maximums

any time a new input value exceeds the lowest of the two captured values, replace that lowest value with the new value.

When all done, the two captured values will be the max and next to max values.

You can easily extend this to require the difference be at least 3 between the two values.